# Nothing to build c++

Tags: c++

I have to say I'm beginner in programming, and I'm trying to make a loto program. A program that generates 7 random numbers. I'm using stack to store numbers.

Here is my code:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <stack>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <ctime>
 using namespace std;

 int main()
{
   srand(time(NULL));
   int v[7];
   int i = 0;
   stack<int> myStack;

while (v[i]< v[7])
{
    v[i] = 1+(rand()% 38);
    i++;
    myStack.push(v[i]);
}
int j = 1;

while(!myStack.empty())
{

    cout << j << " broj je: " << myStack.top() << endl;
    myStack.pop();
    j++;
}
cin >> v[1];
}
```

When I build it says it's okay. But when I try to run it, it prints `Info: Nothing to build for loto3`, just for a second and then it vanishes, then console stays empty, but program is still running because I can terminate it.

I'm using gcc, when I try to compile a basic hello world program it runs with no problem.

Comment: Maybe you should show your Makefile so we can debug the build issue.

Comment: again i say i'm total beginner, if you can simplify for me i would be thankfull

Comment: Your code builds fine in coliru http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4638c5a7b23faa1a, however clang indicated a array out of bounds access at `while (v[i] < v[7])`. Your array has a size of 7 and you are accessing the 8. element.

Comment: Although your code did not output anything on ideone because you did not initialize v before while (v[i]< v[7]) and also it is an out of bounds access like Denis mentioned which invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: ***again i say i'm total beginner, if you can simplify for me i would be thankfull*** Its nearly impossible to help with a build issue when we have to guess how you are building.

Comment: drescherjm Isn't 'int v [7];' for that?
Denis Black So i should make i = 1?

Comment: ***drescherjm Isn't 'int v [7];' for that?*** No. You did not put any values in the array so they are filled with random values. ***So i should make i = 1*** No. You should use `int v [8];` if you plan on using v[7].

Comment: In c++ (and many other programming languages) arrays go from 0 to n-1.  So your `int v[8]` has 8 elements: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 & 7.

Comment: Maybe you want to replace: `while (v[i]< v[7])`  with `while (i < 7)`. I have no idea what you are trying to do with `while (v[i]< v[7])` and how that matches your question.

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is: there isn't anything to build because the code isn't out of date. You're just seeing a message from the build system, which I'm assuming is an IDE (Eclipse? MS tools? Which one?)

The clue is that your program is executing because you can terminate it. You actually have a few bugs -- the size of the `v` array should be 8, not 7. Another bug is the last line of main: `cin >> v[1]`. If you don't have an infinite loop, the program might be waiting for you to type something (but you don't know that because the program hasn't told you that it's waiting for input.)

Also, it's proper form to return a value from a function that has a return type other than `void`. `main()` returns an integer value, so you also want to add `return 0` as the last statement. Of course, you can return any integer value you like, but convention holds that returning zero indicates successful execution (no errors.)

Somewhat corrected code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  srand(time(NULL));

  int v[8];
  int i = 0;
  stack<int> myStack;

  cout << "Seeding random values..." << endl;

  while (v[i]< v[7])
  {
    v[i] = 1+(rand()% 38);
    i++;
    myStack.push(v[i]);
  }

  int j = 1;

  while(!myStack.empty())
  {
    cout << j << " broj je: " << myStack.top() << endl;
    myStack.pop();
    j++;
  }

  cout << "Enter a value for v[1]: ";
  cin >> v[1];

  return 0;
}
```

If you have an infinite loop in the first `while` loop, you will never see the "Enter a value for v[1]" prompt. Otherwise, you'll get the prompt to enter a value and your program should terminate correctly.

Comment: I don't understand what  "while (v[i]< v[7])" part does.  Why not use "i < 7"

Comment: Thank you for your help man really i appreciate so much it worked.

Comment: @KadirErdemDemir: Neither do I, but, the again, it's not my code. Giving the OP some hints on what's broken; it's not helpful to try and read the OP's mind on an incompletely specified problem.

Comment: @FilipTrajkoski: Glad to help. `cout` is a fairly powerful debugging tool -- don't hesitate to output messages so that you can tell where your program is currently executing. (And click the accepted answer icon)

Comment: why easy when you can do it hard , i corrected it and used "i<7". im just trying evrything to see can it work

Comment: @FilipTrajkoski: You could also replace the second while loop with `for (int j = 1; !myStack.empty(); ++j)` if you want to be more compact. You would also be able to eliminate the extra `j++` at the end of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Some simplifications.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

inline void keep_window_open()
{
    cin.clear();
    cout << "Please enter a character to exit\n";
    char ch;
    cin >> ch;
    return;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    constexpr int number_count {7};
    stack<int> myStack;

    // use a for loop as you know the number of repetitions
    for(int i {0}; i<number_count; ++i)
    {
        myStack.push(1+(rand()% 38)); // no need for an inbetween variable
    }

    int j {1};
    while(!myStack.empty())
    {
        /* Next line: j++ uses the post increment notation.
           It increments after each cout. */
        cout << j++ << " broj je: " << myStack.top() << endl;
        myStack.pop();
    }

    keep_window_open();

    return 0;
}
```

Anyhow, I wouldn't use a stack because it's a pain to sort, you might want to order the output. Also, you should add a mechanism to check for doubles.

Comment: Yes just to leave it open. is there anything else to do so it stays open?
I corrected both while loops to for loops.

Comment: @FilipTrajkoski You can use `cin.get();`, `std::getchar()` or `system("pause")` to keep the console open. There are different possibilities depending on your OS. Comparing to check for doubles, sure, but again, a stack is not made for that.

Comment: @FilipTrajkoski I added a function to keep the console open. This is the method from [Bjarne's Programming Principles and Practice Using C++ book](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/).